# javafx Imageview load an image but not others

Tags: javafx, imageview

I'm using ImageView ( javafx ), I tried to load an image (jpg), it works, and when i try to load another it is not (I tried gif, png, also another jpg). I also tried to change the name of the image loaded before, and same, it doesn't load.
It just work with the first image, with same name.

I declared this :

```
    @FXML 
    private ImageView imageView;
```

AND this is the code that worked:

```
    InputStream is = this.mainApp.getClass().getResourceAsStream("..\\resources\\images\\facture\\recuBank\\2015\\22-12-2015\\12080351_10206938666998884_3823913475123618229_o.jpg");
    if(is != null)  
    {
        Image img = new Image(is);
        this.imageView.setImage(img);
    }
```

AND this doens't worked :

```
    // I renamed the first image
    InputStream is = this.mainApp.getClass().getResourceAsStream("..\\resources\\images\\facture\\recuBank\\2015\\22-12-2015\\a.jpg");   
    if(is != null)  
    {
        Image img = new Image(is);
        this.imageView.setImage(img);
    }
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: SORRY I DON'T KNOW WHY THE FIRST LINE DOESN'T APPEAR, IT WAS a SALUTATION.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the path to the second image is correct? Are you sure the second JPG image is a valid image? What does getResourceAsStream() return? Do you get an error somewhere? If so, please edit your start post to add it..

Comment: thank you  KompjoeFriek ! by inspecting the return value of getResourceAsStream(), I got the idea of refreshing the folder, and it works.( see answer )

Answer (score 0):

WOW I solved it just by doing a REFRESH in folder "resources", in my project (in Eclise).

I was adding the images directly in the folder, so in my project, Eclise is not aware that any change happened.